# How do you get available Area Paths from Azure DevOps Services REST API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I cannot find how to retrieve the Area Paths from the API.  I was able to get to the Iteration Paths but not Area Paths.

*I'm technically using the c# wrapper*

I've tried going through

- ProjectHttpClient.GetProject()
- ProjectHttpClient.GetProjectPropertiesAsync();
- WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.GetFieldAsync("System.AreaPath");
- WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemTypeFieldWithReferencesAsync();
- I've looked in the WorkHttpClient too since I got the iterations from there.
- I've looked through the docs and couldn't find anything.  Even searching for "area" brings back no results.

[image: azure devops project settings]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are the API calls you are looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification%20nodes/get%20classification%20nodes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes?$depth={$depth}&api-version=5.0
```

This will give you root nodes and their children, after that you can query individual children, example of the child I'm getting:

```
id            : 32
identifier    : GUID
name          : childname
structureType : area
hasChildren   : False
path          : \parent\Area\childname
url           : https://dev.azure.com/xxx/yyy/_apis/wit/classificationNodes/Are
                as/childname
```

C# API:

```cs
_destinationTfs = new VssConnection(new Uri(TfsUri), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, AccessToken));
_witClient = _destinationTfs.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

var areaPathNode = await _witClient.GetClassificationNodeAsync("PROJECT_NAME", TreeStructureGroup.Areas, depth: 1);
// areaPathNode.Children will contain all your area paths.
```

ps. It's extremely well hidden in the API docs

Comment: Thank you! I’ll test this on Monday and get back to you.

Comment: When try that uri, even with the depth param, i get hasChildren = true, but no children are actually returned (e.g. no "children" attribute). What could cause this?